# Como enviar 3 parametros por http.get desde angular a spring boot

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, servicio, http-get

necesito ayuda con esta petición, hasta el momento solo hacia una petición con un solo parámetro, pero ahora tengo la necesidad de enviar 3 parámetros a spring.
en spring ya tengo como voy a recibir los 3 parámetros, lo k no puedo es enviar desde mi servicio en angular. me podrían ayudar pliss

codigo del controlller spring

```
@GetMapping({"/api/listafiltrada"})
        public List<Persona> lista(
            @RequestParam("nombres") String xnombres, @RequestParam("tipoper") String xtipoper, @RequestParam("estado") int xestado){
            System.out.println("nombres "+xnombres+", tipo "+xtipoper+", estado "+xestado);
            return perepositorio.listafilt(xnombres, xtipoper, xestado);
            }

ya en el repositorio hago la consulta para filtrar una lista para devolver al angular.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para adjuntar parámetros de consulta en una petición GET tienes dos opciones:

1.- Intercalar los parametros y sus valores directamente en la url:

```
this.httpClient.get(`/api/listafiltrada?nombres=${name}&tipoper=${tipo}&estado=${status}`)
```

2.- O definirlos en un objeto con las parejas de clave/valor en la propiedad `params` del objeto de opciones que acepta el método `get` como segundo argumento.

```
this.httpClient.get('/api/listafiltrada', { 
  params: {
    nombres: name,
    tipoper: tipo,
    estado: status,
  }
})
```

slds

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, intenté hacer lo que me dijiste y obtengo 2 errores.
1.- error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
      The last overload gave the following error.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | string[]'.
    
    210       est:estado


2.- en la llamada al servicio me sale lo siguiente.
error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.
    
    181       this.perserv.getlistfiltrada(this.filtronombre,this.filtrotipo,this.filtroestado).subscribe(

Comment: mi codigo en el servicio quedó asi

```getlistfiltrada(nombres:string, tipo: string, estado:number){
  this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'/listafiltrada',{
    params: {
      nom: nombres,
      tipoper: tipo,
      est:estado
    }
  })
  }```

Comment: Con los dos trozos de código que incluyes, en principio el fallo te lo esta dando porque la propiedad `filtroestado` que tienes en el componente es del tipo `string | string[]` y en el parámetro `estado` del método del servicio esperas un `number`.  Y otra cosa, no te olvides de hacer `return` en el método.

Comment: oooh lo del return se me habia pasado, gracias, y por lo del primer error he revisado y mis varibles en el .ts los tengo asi 
**filtronombre:string = "ANA";
filtrotipo:string = "A";
filtroestado:number = 1;**
//le puse valores para hacer k funcione para luego asignarle los datos.
y en el service tambien lo agarro como string, string, number.
ya lo revise varias veces y no doy con el error, algo se  me debe estar pasando, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. :)

Comment: Estas usando las versión 11 o anterior de angular, ¿correcto? Es que he mirado y no me acordaba que en las versiones anteriores los `params` solo aceptaban `strings`. Por tanto tendrás que mapear el valor de `estado` a un `string` o usar una versión más reciente de angular. slds